# How to new a unix domain socket file with mode(777) in ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, unix-socket

I create an unix domain socket file using this code: `UNIXServer.new('tmp/my_socket.sock')`
It did create socket file but the default file mode is `srwxrwxr-x`,
How can I specific the mode when creating, I found nothing about this problem in ruby doc. Can someone help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`File#chmod`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-chmod):

```
UNIXServer.new('tmp/my_socket.sock') 
File.chmod 0777, 'tmp/my_socket.sock'
```

Comment: is there another way to do that?

Comment: There are thousands, but I believe this one is a proper one. Why?